# Form background color gray level sequencing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form named grayForm in excel which I want to change the gray level automatically for photometric data acquisition. I wrote the following code, but it does not show the gray level color change until it is completed--that is, when the red gray level 255 is reached. varying the 'Sleep' wait time does not help. However, when I insert a 'stop' as shown and continue manually, it steps through the 'for loop' with gray levels changing just fine, so the code seems correct. What code change/addition is needed to enable this to change without 'stop' interruption?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    cOffset = 4
    grayForm.Show 0
    grayForm.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    For i = 0 To 16
        temp1 = Str(i + cOffset)
        temp1 = Replace(temp1, Chr(32), "")     'Remove space " "
        nGray = Cells(i + cOffset, "B") 'reads values 0, 17, 31, ... 255 from column B
        Range(temp).Select: ActiveCell.Value = nGray
        grayForm.BackColor = RGB(nGray, 0, 0)
        'Stop
        Sleep 200 ' millisecond delay
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try `DoEvents`?

Comment: Sounds like a horrible UI.

Comment: Also - I am slightly concerned that, in a 17-iteration loop, that you are even noticing this. How ancient is your hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Stop` with `DoEvents`.

`DoEvents` will allow Excel to "repaint" itself. `Sleep()` stops execution, which is likely why you don't even see the repaint from that.

So try this:

```
For i = 0 To 16
    temp1 = Str(i + cOffset)
    temp1 = Replace(temp1, Chr(32), "")     'Remove space " "
    nGray = Cells(i + cOffset, "B") 'reads values 0, 17, 31, ... 255 from column B
    Range(temp).Select: ActiveCell.Value = nGray
    grayForm.BackColor = RGB(nGray, 0, 0)
    DoEvents
Next i
```

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function) on the `DoEvents` function.